# why I can run docker-compose in Github action without install it

Tags: docker-compose, github-actions, cicd

I make a copy/paste from [the link](https://faun.pub/building-a-ci-cd-pipeline-with-github-actions-and-docker-part-1-a9d8709c31fb) here. I am confused about why I can run **docker-compose** without installing it. When I test locally using "act", it will give me an error about ***docker-compose command not found***.

```
name: CI-dev-pipeline
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: lucasalt/act_base:latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: "<INSERT_NAME_OF_REPOSITORY>"

    - name: Build docker
      run: | 
        docker-compose -f ./<REPO_NAME>/docker-compose.test.yml -p testing up -d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a docker-image from "lucasalt/act_base".
If you look at the description of the images it states:

> act_base is a custom runner for the act project. This image contain Node, npm, yarn, docker and docker-compose.

Meaning that it already downloads `docker-compose` etc. for you.

Comment: Thank you, May I ask one more? how about this one? why it can run docker-compose?
https://github.com/bahmutov/chat.io/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L16

Comment: @JoeYo This is using a docker-image that doesn't have anything but basic ubuntu. You will need to install docker-compose via apt before running docker-compose.

Comment: I agree, but when I checked their Action CI workflow,  `docker-compose` is still working. I am not it is about caching?  or default github action container already install docker compose.

Comment: @JoeYo the image they are using by declaring: `runs-on: ubuntu-20.04` includes `docker-compose` as default software. See [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md) for more information.